# ADD TO CART button is not working Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing the problem for several days, actually, ADD TO CART button is not working. In debug mode of Chrome below messages are generated :

> Refused to execute script from 'http://www.planet-gadgets.ru/index.php/ajaxcartsuper/ajaxcart/add/uenc/aHR0…Gf08Ab/?callback=jQuery172003263813592517817_1484323397815&_=1484323616853' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
> at Function.hide (prototype.js:1931)
> at klass.baseInitialize (controls.js:88)
> at klass.initialize (controls.js:347)
> at new klass (prototype.js:101)
> at klass.initAutocomplete (js.js:349)
> at (index):204

Any kind of help will be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having same issue. Finding for solution

Answer (score 0):

According to the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528211/refused-to-execute-script-from-because-its-mime-type-application-json-is) you need to change the type to `application/javascript` instead of `text/javascript`.